# Beginner question - How do summation notation work with 2 variables?

Tags: summation, notation

I am having trouble understanding this notation, I am not very well versed in math, but my understanding is the top part should be a number to tell us how many terms, but there is a n-1 here which is confusing me. As well, there are n and a k variable, from what I have seen there should only be one variable? Could someone please explain how this sigma would expand? The two areas I do not understand are the n and the k variables and how the limit could be n-1?

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lfloor(n+k)k\rfloor
$$

Answer (score 2):

The sum notation tells you with which number you begin summing and with which you end. In your index of the sum sign (called capital Sigma) there is a running index, here it is $k$.

It tells you it begins with $k=1$ meaning your first summand is the term on the right with $k=1$ being inserted into the term. Here it would be floor$((n+1)\cdot 1)$. Because your index $k$ runs from 1 to $n-1$, it goes through all the numbers between 1 and $n-1$ with that number being inserted into the term on the RHS. That means, the next summand will be with $k=2$ (if your $n$ is greater or equal to 3. Notice, that if $n=2$, your $k$ would only start at 1 and end at $n-1=1$, so there would only be one summand with $k=1$.). With $k=2$ you would have the summand floor$((n+2)\cdot 2)$. You mentioned you got confused with the other variable $n$. As you (probably) have it as an arbitrary positive integer, you just leave it there in the sum. It acts as any natural number and does not change your summands. Now, that you know how every summand looks like, this sum has the form:

$$\text{floor}((n+1)\cdot 1) + \text{floor}((n+2)\cdot 2) + \text{floor}((n+3)\cdot 3) + ... + \text{floor}((n+(n-2))\cdot (n-2)) + \text{floor}((n+(n-1))\cdot (n-1))$$

As a side note, there is also an empty sum. In this case, let $n=1$. Then your $k$ would start at 1 and would have to end at $n-1=0$. So, your start is already greater than your end index. In this case, we say that the sum is empty. It does not have any summands and is thus equals to 0. Hope it helped.